# How to calculate bezier curve control points that avoid objects?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bezier, music-notation

Specifically, I'm working in canvas with javascript.

Basically, I have objects which have boundaries that I want to avoid, but still surround with a bezier curve. However, I'm not even sure where to begin to write an algorithm that would move control points to avoid colliding.

The problem is in the image below, even if you're not familiar with music notation, the problem should still be fairly clear. The points of the curve are the red dots

[image]

Also, I have access to the bounding boxes of each note, which includes the stem.

[image]

So naturally, collisions must be detected between the bounding boxes and the curves (some direction here would be good, but I've been browsing and see that there's a decent amount of info on this). But what happens after collisions have been detected? What would have to happen to calculate control points locations to make something that looked more like:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about automatically putting the curve above the notes?  The problem is that there are an infinite number of solutions where the curve is above the notes.  I could see a non-automatic solution where you move the red dots representing the control points into position manually.

Comment: I am not looking for a non-automatic solution. Just something that, at the very least, approximates the best position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Bezier approach

Initially the question is a broad one - perhaps even to broad for SO as there are many different scenarios that needs to be taken into consideration to make a "one solution that fits them all". It's a whole project in its self. Therefor I will present a *basis* for a solution which you can build upon - it's not a complete solution (but close to one..). I added some suggestions for additions at the end.

**The basic steps for this solutions are:**

Group the notes into two groups, a left and a right part.

The control points are then based on the largest angle from the first (end) point and distance to any of the other notes in that group, and the last end point to any point in the second group.

The resulting angles from the two groups are then doubled (max 90°) and used as basis to calculate the control points (basically a point rotation). The distance can be further trimmed using a tension value.

The angle, doubling, distance, tension and padding offset will allow for fine-tuning to get the best over-all result. There might be special cases which need additional conditional checks but that is out of scope here to cover (it won't be a full key-ready solution but provide a good basis to work further upon).

A couple of snapshots from the process:

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

The main code in the example is split into two section, two loops that parses each half to find the maximum angle as well as the distance. This could be combined into a single loop and have a second iterator to go from right to middle in addition to the one going from left to middle, but for simplicity and better understand what goes on I split them into two loops (and introduced a bug in the second half - just be aware. I'll leave it as an exercise):

```
var dist1 = 0,  // final distance and angles for the control points
    dist2 = 0,
    a1 = 0,
    a2 = 0;

// get min angle from the half first points
for(i = 2; i < len * 0.5 - 2; i += 2) {

    var dx = notes[i  ] - notes[0],      // diff between end point and
        dy = notes[i+1] - notes[1],      // current point.
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy), // get distance
        a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);          // get angle

    if (a < a1) {                        // if less (neg) then update finals
        a1 = a;
        dist1 = dist;
    }
}

if (a1 < -0.5 * Math.PI) a1 = -0.5 * Math.PI;      // limit to 90 deg.
```

And the same with the second half but here we flip around the angles so they are easier to handle by comparing current point with end point instead of end point compared with current point. After the loop is done we flip it 180°:

```
// get min angle from the half last points
for(i = len * 0.5; i < len - 2; i += 2) {

    var dx = notes[len-2] - notes[i],
        dy = notes[len-1] - notes[i+1],
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy),
        a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    if (a > a2) {
        a2 = a;
        if (dist2 < dist) dist2 = dist;            //bug here*
    }
}

a2 -= Math.PI;                                     // flip 180 deg.
if (a2 > -0.5 * Math.PI) a2 = -0.5 * Math.PI;      // limit to 90 deg.
```

*(the bug is that longest distance is used even if a shorter distance point has greater angle - I'll let it be for now as this is meant as an example. It can be fixed by reversing the iteration.).*

The relationship I found works good is the angle difference between the floor and the point times two:

```
var da1 = Math.abs(a1);                            // get angle diff
var da2 = a2 < 0 ? Math.PI + a2 : Math.abs(a2);

a1 -= da1*2;                                       // double the diff
a2 += da2*2;
```

Now we can simply calculate the control points and use a tension value to fine tune the result:

```
var t = 0.8,                                       // tension
    cp1x = notes[0]     + dist1 * t * Math.cos(a1),
    cp1y = notes[1]     + dist1 * t * Math.sin(a1),
    cp2x = notes[len-2] + dist2 * t * Math.cos(a2),
    cp2y = notes[len-1] + dist2 * t * Math.sin(a2);
```

And voila:

```
ctx.moveTo(notes[0], notes[1]);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, notes[len-2], notes[len-1]);
ctx.stroke();
```

### Adding tapering effect

To create the curve more visually pleasing a tapering can be added simply by doing the following instead:

Instead of stroking the path after the first Bezier curve has been added adjust the control points with a slight angle offset. Then continue the path by adding another Bezier curve going from right to left, and finally fill it (`fill()` will close the path implicit):

```
// first path from left to right
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(notes[0], notes[1]);                    // start point
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, notes[len-2], notes[len-1]);

// taper going from right to left
var taper = 0.15;                                  // angle offset
cp1x = notes[0] + dist1*t*Math.cos(a1-taper);
cp1y = notes[1] + dist1*t*Math.sin(a1-taper);
cp2x = notes[len-2] + dist2*t*Math.cos(a2+taper);
cp2y = notes[len-1] + dist2*t*Math.sin(a2+taper);

// note the order of the control points
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp2x, cp2y, cp1x, cp1y, notes[0], notes[1]);
ctx.fill();                                        // close and fill
```

### Final result (with pseudo notes - tension = 0.7, padding = 10)

[image: taper]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/4EkfK/)**

Suggested improvements:

- If both groups' distances are large, or angles are steep, they could probably be used as a sum to reduce tension (distance) or increase it (angle).
- A dominance/area factor could affect the distances. Dominance indicating where the most tallest parts are shifted at (does it lay more in the left or right side, and affects tension for each side accordingly). This could possibly/potentially be enough on its own but needs to be tested.
- Taper angle offset should also have a relationship with the sum of distance. In some cases the lines crosses and does not look so good. Tapering could be replaced with a manual approach parsing Bezier points (manual implementation) and add a distance between the original points and the points for the returning path depending on array position.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Nice approach! Splitting the target into left & right parts fits well with cubic Bezier control points which affect the left & right parts of the curve. Yep...very nice!

Comment: This is totally awesome! Thanks again for the very thorough and very well explained solutions.

Answer (score 6):

### Cardinal spline and filtering approach

If you're open to use a non-Bezier approach then the following can give an approximate curve above the note stems.

This solutions consists of 4 steps:

1. Collect top of notes/stems
2. Filter away "dips" in the path
3. Filter away points on same slope
4. Generate a cardinal spline curve

This is a prototype solution so I have not tested it against every possible combination there is. But it should give you a good starting point and basis to continue on.

The first step is easy, collect points representing the top of the note stem - for the demo I use the following point collection which slightly represents the image you have in the post. They are arranged in x, y order:

```
var notes = [60,40, 100,35, 140,30, 180,25, 220,45, 260,25, 300,25, 340,45];
```

which would be represented like this:

[image: image1]

Then I created a simple multi-pass algorithm that filters away dips and points on the same slope. The steps in the algorithm are as follows:

- While there is a `anotherPass` (true) it will continue, or until max number of passes set initially
- The point is copied to another array as long as the `skip` flag isn't set
- Then it will compare current point with next to see if it has a down-slope
- If it does, it will compare the next point with the following and see if it has an up-slope
- If it does it is considered a dip and the `skip` flag is set so next point (the current middle point) won't be copied
- The next filter will compare slope between current and next point, and next point and the following.
- If they are the same `skip` flag is set.
- If it had to set a `skip` flag it will also set `anotherPass` flag.
- If no points where filtered (or max passes is reached) the loop will end

The core function is as follows:

```
while(anotherPass && max) {
    
    skip = anotherPass = false;
    
    for(i = 0; i < notes.length - 2; i += 2) {
    
        if (!skip) curve.push(notes[i], notes[i+1]);
        skip = false;
        
        // if this to next points goes downward
        // AND the next and the following up we have a dip
        if (notes[i+3] >= notes[i+1] && notes[i+5] <= notes[i+3]) {
            skip = anotherPass = true;
        }
        
        // if slope from this to next point = 
        // slope from next and following skip
        else if (notes[i+2] - notes[i] === notes[i+4] - notes[i+2] &&
            notes[i+3] - notes[i+1] === notes[i+5] - notes[i+3]) {
            skip = anotherPass = true;
        }
    }
    curve.push(notes[notes.length-2], notes[notes.length-1]);
    max--;

    if (anotherPass && max) {
        notes = curve;
        curve = [];
    }
}
```

The result of the first pass would be after offsetting all the points on the y-axis - notice that the dipping note is ignored:

[image: image2]

After running through all necessary passes the final point array would be represented as this:

[image: image3]

The only step left is to smoothen the curve. For this I have used my own implementation of a cardinal spline (licensed under MIT and can be **[found here](https://github.com/epistemex/cardinal-spline-js)**) which takes an array with x,y points and smooths it adding interpolated points based on a tension value.

It won't generate a perfect curve but the result from this would be:

[image: image6]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/mvcmk/)**

There are ways to improve the visual result which I haven't addressed, but I will leave it to you to do that if you feel it's needed. Among those could be:

- Find center of points and increase the offset depending on angle so it arcs more at top
- The end points of the smoothed curve sometimes curls slightly - this can be fixed by adding an initial point right below the first point as well at the end. This will force the curve to have better looking start/end.
- You could draw double curve to make a taper effect (thin beginning/end, thicker in the middle) by using the first point in this list on another array but with a very small offset at top of the arc, and then render it on top.

The algorithm was created ad-hook for this answer so it's obviously not properly tested. There could be special cases and combination throwing it off but I think it's a good start.

Known weaknesses:

- It assumes the distance between each stem is the same for the slope detection. This needs to be replaced with a factor based comparison in case the distance varies within a group.
- It compares the slope with exact values which may fail if floating point values are used. Compare with an epsilon/tolerance

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough response! Playing with the fiddle it certainly works very well. Some more jarring combinations tend to throw it off a bit, but I'm sure that's fixable given some modifications. If I can't find a solution for bezier curves this may have to be the route I take. But bezier curves definitely create the most aesthetically pleasing curves for this use case, so I still want to shoot for that.